# Python: value that occurs the most in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a two list as follows

```
x = ['a','a','b','c','b','a']
```

and

```
x = ['a','a','b','c','c','d']
```

I'm trying to find which values occur the most in each of these lists. This is what I have tried.

```
def unique_values(output,input):
    for i in input:
        if i not in output:
            output.append(i)
k = []
for i in k:
    unique_values(k,x)
    y.remove(i)
```

I've gotten this far but I cant figure out how to stop the `for i in k:` before it removes all the values in the list.

Comment: "for i in k" == "for i in []" (won't run) This said, you can check: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections#collections.Counter

Comment: `from collections import Counter; print Counter(x).most_common()[0]`

Comment: @MartjinPieters: `.most_common(1)` (`max()` can be faster than `sorted(reverse=True)[0]`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `Counter` module from `collections`, if you want to find the occurrences of each element in the list: -

```
>>> x = ['a','a','b','c','c','d']

>>> from collections import Counter
>>> count = Counter(x)
>>> count
Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': 1})
>>> count.most_common()
[('a', 2), ('c', 2), ('b', 1), ('d', 1)]
```

So, the first two elements are most common in your list.

```
>>> count.most_common()[0]
('a', 2)
>>> count.most_common()[1]
('c', 2)
```

or, you also pass parameter to `most_common()` to specify how many `most-common` elements you want: -

```
>>> count.most_common(2)
[('a', 2), ('c', 2)]
```

**Update : -**

You can also find out the `max` count first, and then find total number of elements with that value, and then you can use it as parameter in `most_common()`: -

```
>>> freq_list = count.values()
>>> freq_list
[2, 2, 1, 1]
>>> max_cnt = max(freq_list)
>>> total = freq_list.count(max_cnt)

>>> most_common = count.most_common(total)
[('a', 2), ('c', 2)]

>>> [elem[0] for elem in most_common]
['a', 'c']
```

Comment: why would someone rename Counter as cntr? This is very unpythonic.

Comment: it not necessary using slice to get most commont in the list. just supplment n in most_common(n)

Comment: @ShawnZhang.. Yeah right. I just used it, because there were two most common elements. I'll add it though.

Comment: Note: if `len(x)` is large then `count.most_common(2)` is more efficient than `count.most_common()[:2]`

Comment: is there any way to change `x` but make sure that even if there is only 1 or more than 1 most common that it still produces all most commons?

Comment: @user1871081.. I don't understand. What do you exactly want?

Comment: @user1871081.. Check the updated post. I think you are looking for the last solution.

Comment: Sorry for being quite vague. The update was what I was looking for. Is there a way to have the data printed without the frequency's so that it just showed `['a','c']`

Comment: Just use a list comprehension on `l` obtained, to get just the first element.

Comment: @user1871081.. Added that part.

Comment: You don't need `Counter.most_common()` method which sorts the frequencies. `freqdist = Counter(x); max_freq = max(freqdist.itervalues()); most_common = [item for item, freq in freqdist.iteritems() if freq == max_freq] # O(n)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I tried that but I get an error that says Counter has no attribute .intervalues on the line `max_freq = max(freqdist.itervalues())`

Comment: @user1871081.. Are you sure you are using `itervalues()` on `Counter(x)` instance? Because you wrote - `intervalues()`. Please check.

Comment: @user1871081: If you are on Python 3 then use `.values()`, `.items()` instead. These methods return ["views" on Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) instead of lists. [`.itervalues()` returns an iterator over the values](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) on Python 2. Counter is a dict subclass so dict's methods are available.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
max(zip((x.count(item) for item in set(x)), set(x)))
```

First, we get a collection containing no duplicate elements using set.

```
>>> set(x)
{'a', 'c', 'b'}
```

Then, we count how many times each element is in x. This will return a generator object, you can make it a list to see its values (by using "[ ... ]" instead of "( ... )" ), it would return [3, 1, 2].

```
>>> (x.count(item) for item in set(x))
```

Then, we take the counts and pair it with the elements using zip. The number of occurrences first, for the next step. You can see its value by using list( ... ) on it, it would return [(3, 'a'), (1, 'c'), (2, 'b')].

```
>>> zip((x.count(item) for item in set(x)), set(x))
```

Finally, we find which of the pairs occurs most times using max.

```
>>> max(zip((x.count(item) for item in set(x)), set(x)))
(3, 'a')
```

As for the second value, the solution is a bit lengthier. The above is used within a list comprehension:

```
>>> [mitem for mitem in zip((x.count(item) for item in set(x)),set(x)) if mitem[0] == max((x.count(item) for item in set(x)))]
[(2, 'a'), (2, 'c')]
```

Comment: Right after the statement, following the three parentheses. Example: ...)))[-1]

Comment: The solution is `O(N**4)` it is unreasonable even for moderate-sized lists e.g., `N=1000` it would require `~10**12` operations. You could easily improve it to `O(N**2)` that is still bad in  comparison with `Counter()` which provides `O(N*log m)` time complexity where `m` is the number of most common elements.