# Mode of a List - Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to write my own function that finds the **mode** of a list but it sputters when there are **multiple modes**. Can someone help me in adding something to the function that deals with the case with multiple modes. Thanks in advance!

```
def ModeList(nums):
    subscript = 0
    while subscript < len(nums):
        if nums.count(nums[subscript]) > nums.count(nums[subscript + 1]):
            return "The mode is " + str( nums[subscript] ) + "."
        else:
            subscript += 1

print ModeList( [2,4,6,8,6,8] )
```

Comment: What output do you expect? Any single mode?

Comment: Yes, the expected output should be any mode.

Comment: Your logic is flawed. It will always report that the first value is the mode, if it appears more often than the second, ignoring the entire rest of the list. (e.g. `[1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3]` would return `1`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: value that occurs the most in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707457/python-value-that-occurs-the-most-in-a-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest is to use a [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def ModeList(lst):
    return Counter(lst).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def ModeList(lst):
...     return Counter(lst).most_common(1)[0][0]
... 
>>> ModeList( [2,4,6,8,6,8] )
8
```

Add in `itertools.groupby()` if you need *all* values:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def ModeList(lst):
    counts = Counter(lst)
    grouped = groupby(counts.most_common(), itemgetter(1))
    return [i[0] for i in next(grouped)[1]]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> 
>>> def ModeList(lst):
...     counts = Counter(lst)
...     grouped = groupby(counts.most_common(), itemgetter(1))
...     return [i[0] for i in next(grouped)[1]]
... 
>>> ModeList( [2,4,6,8,6,8] )
[8, 6]
```

Without importing, use a dictionary to track counts, then sort by value:

```
def ModeList(lst):
    counts = {}
    for item in lst:
        counts[item] = counts.get(item, 0) + 1
    return sorted(counts, key=counts.get, reverse=True)[0]
```

or for a list:

```
def ModeList(lst):
    counts = {}
    for item in lst:
        counts[item] = counts.get(item, 0) + 1
    bycount = sorted(counts, key=counts.get)
    result = [bycount.pop()]
    while counts and counts[bycount[-1]] == counts[result[0]]:
        result.append(bycount.pop())
    return result
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without importing anything?

Comment: @ToxicTechnetium Why?

Comment: @ToxicTechnetium: Added a plain version.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Plain version will only return first mode if multiple modes exist, no?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: yes, both return *one*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Nvm, just saw the OP's new comment under the question itself. Thought originally it was supposed to return a list of all modes. You are correct.